# sed regular expression failed on solaris

Tags: regex, sed, posix, solaris

Under Solaris 5.10, Why this regexp doesn't match a line like tag="12447"

```
 sed  "s/tag=\"[0-9]+\"/emptytag/" test.xml
```

(I noticed that -r is not implemented in the sed version)

Comment: One option is to use gsed (regarding unsupported option -r).

Comment: Indeed, but gsed is not installed on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strict posix mode, the `+` sign cannot be used to represent "one or more" of something. You can use a range of `{1,}` instead (escaped of course):

```
echo 'tag="12447"' | sed --posix "s/tag=\"[0-9]\{1,\}\"/emptytag/"
emptytag
```

Note that you don't actually need the `--posix`, I was just using it to disable all GNU extensions in my version of `sed`:

```
echo 'tag="12447"' | sed "s/tag=\"[0-9]\{1,\}\"/emptytag/"
emptytag
```